# Javascript Image() getting natural width and height

Tags: javascript

I have a problem on how I could extract the value(s) of an image(`img`)'s `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` upon loading it via Javascript.

Basically I have this code snippet:

```
var newImage = new Image(),
    naturalWidth = 0,
    naturalHeight = 0;
newImage.onload = function() {
    naturalWidth = newImage.width;
    naturalHeight = newImage.height;
}
newImage.src = imageObject.imageArea.filename;
alert("Image Size: " + naturalWidth + "x"+  naturalHeight);
```

I don't know if the problem is passing the value of `newImage.width` to `naturalWidth` or whatsoever.

How can this be resolved? So basically I wanted to the problem here is how to extract the values of `newImage.width` to pass it to `naturalWidth`.

Comment: What's the problem? `naturalWidth` may not be set when you alert. It's only set in the `onload` callback. Move the alert there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the image loads asynchronously and `onload` is called sometime in the future AFTER your `alert()` code runs.  You can test the `height` and `width` inside the `onload` handler or you can call a function from there and pass it the `height` and `width`:

```
var newImage = new Image(),
newImage.onload = function() {
    var naturalWidth = newImage.width;
    var naturalHeight = newImage.height;
    // use the height and width here
    alert("Image Size: " + naturalWidth + "x"+  naturalHeight);
}
newImage.src = imageObject.imageArea.filename;
```

OR

```
var newImage = new Image(),
newImage.onload = function() {
    // pass the height and width in a function call
    callMyFunc(newImage.width, newImage.height);
}
newImage.src = imageObject.imageArea.filename;
```

---

FYI, there are also `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` properties (which are the unscaled height and width of the image) on the image element that you may also be interested in.

Comment: I wanted to show the alert after `newImage.onload()`. I've tried that approach yet, I wanted to extract the values outside of that method that's why the alert placed at the last line.

Comment: @Dr.Java - you can't do it the way you're trying to do it.  Those values are not known until sometime LATER when the `onload` callback is called.    This is how an asychronous javascript callback works.  Your two choices are to process the size values IN the `onload` handler or call a function from the `onload` handler and pass it those values.  That's how asynchronous callbacks works.  You have to learn to program with them.

Comment: I see then. Is there any possible way to transfer/copy the values of `newImage.width` to `naturalWidth` basing from my code snippet above?

Comment: @Dr.Java - please seem my previous comment.  You have two choices and only two choices.

Comment: Uhm, I'm sorry but I can't visualize both solutions. Would it be possible to create a snippet for both solution?

Comment: @Dr.Java - the two options are now in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous,

`alert` gets called before you set `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`

Try this,

```
var newImage = new Image(),
    naturalWidth = 0,
    naturalHeight = 0;
newImage.onload = function() {
    naturalWidth = newImage.width;
    naturalHeight = newImage.height;
    alert("Image Size: " + naturalWidth + "x"+  naturalHeight);
}
newImage.src = imageObject.imageArea.filename;
```

Comment: I wanted to show the alert after `newImage.onload()`. I've tried that approach yet, I wanted to extract the values outside of that method that's why the alert placed at the last line.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Suppose, images take 5 seconds to load, then code inside `onload` will run after 5 secs only. Code written below `onload` function (outside of `onload`) will run immediately. So, if you will use `naturalWidth` / `naturalHeight`, they will have 0 value, as they are going to be set after 5 secs. I hope, I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your alert is called before your image is loaded

```
var newImage = new Image(),
    naturalWidth = 0,
    naturalHeight = 0;
if (newImage.addEventListener) {
  newImage.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert("load complete")
   naturalWidth = newImage.width;
   naturalHeight = newImage.height;

  });
} else {
  // it's IE!
  newImage.attachEvent('onload', function() {
    naturalWidth = newImage.width;
    naturalHeight = newImage.height;
  });
}

newImage.src = "http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/020/f/0/Black_Twitter_icons_by_iconhive.jpg";
 document.getElementById("img_cont").appendChild(newImage)
```

You can check the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29YYP/)

====================================

if you want to use naturalWidth and naturalHeight valus out side the function then we have to poll for those values to be set.

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  if(naturalWidth !=0) {
   clearInterval(timer);
   alert("Image Size: " + naturalWidth + "x"+  naturalHeight);
  }
},100);
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29YYP/1/) for the updated code

Comment: I wanted to show the alert after `newImage.onload()`. I've tried that approach yet, I wanted to extract the values outside of that method that's why the alert placed at the last line.

Comment: Check my updated fiddle and answer, hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Is it really necessary to display the image on HTML to get the value? I was hoping if it's possible to extract the values using plain JS.